# How to query predictionio for a particular app

Tags: machine-learning, predictionio

I have created multiple apps in predictionio.

While inserting events in predictionio, there a parameter accessKey (associated to app) which is passed.

Whereas for queries.json, couldn't find the accessKey parameter.

Sample below:

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>   -d '{   "items": ["i1", "i3"],   "num": 10,   "categories" : ["c4", "c3"],   "blackList": ["i21", "i26", "i40"] }' \
>   http://localhost:8000/queries.json
>
> {"itemScores":[{"item":"i39","score":1.0773502691896257},{"item":"i44","score":1.0773502691896257},{"item":"i14","score":1.0773502691896257},{"item":"i45","score":0.7886751345948129},{"item":"i47","score":0.7618016810571367},{"item":"i6","score":0.7618016810571367},{"item":"i28","score":0.7618016810571367},{"item":"i9","score":0.7618016810571367},{"item":"i29","score":0.6220084679281463},{"item":"i30","score":0.5386751345948129}]}

Now, how to query data for a particular app?

Comment: I could not find any exact solution for this. But, you could deploy the engine in different ports for different apps. Is this feasible and scalable?

Comment: @ANKITHALDAR that wouldn't work for us as we need it for multiple customers in a scale of 500+

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/predictionio-user/JcStTKc-BDw